# Prove $\mathbf{PA} = (\mathbf{PA})(\mathbf{PA})/c$ for all ones matrix $\mathbf{P}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can the following equality be shown for square, real-valued matrices $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{A}$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{PA} = (\mathbf{PA})(\mathbf{PA})/c 
= (\mathbf{PA})(\mathbf{PA})(\mathbf{PA})/c^2 
= \prod_{}^{N} \mathbf{PA}/c^{N-1}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$ is the all ones matrix, $c=\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{1}$, and $\mathbf{1}$ is an all ones column vector?

Comment: I've worked through it algebraically for a small, 2x2 matrix.  I don't know how to show it generally.

Comment: Try to prove that $PAP=cP$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $P$ has rank $1$, and the image of $PA$ is contained in the $1$-dimensional image subspace $W$ of $P$ (so that the rank of $PA$ is at most $1$). Restricted to $W$, the matrix $PA$ acts by a scalar that we can compute by applying $PA$ it to a spanning vector $\def\1{\mathbf 1}\1$ of$~W$:
$$
  PA\,\1=\1 \1^\top \!A\,\1 = \1 c= c\1
\qquad\hbox{since $c=\1^\top \!A\,\1$ is a scalar.}
$$
Then since to the left of $PA$ one is just operating on$~W$, one has $(PA)^nPA=c^nPA$, for $n\geq0$. This is essentially the equation you want to prove, except that it avoids division by$~0$ in case $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\mathbf{PAP}= \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}= (\mathbf{1}^{\top}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{1})\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}=c\mathbf{P}$.